# guess ethernet interface is bounding, where would I find a log that proves or disproves

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

I have a program that is sensitive to ethernet interface changes or bouncing on and off.  The program in question is
a monster (microk8s), so it could be failing for other reasons.

Also, on occasion, I notice chrome complaining of no connectivity. But I'm not on chrome enough to know if this is much more common and correlated to the monster program failures. But I suspect they are correlated.

So I would like to look at a Linux log that would show an interface changing state.  Is there such a Linux log in Ubuntu 18.04?

Would auto-negotiation between 1G and 100M cause the interface to bounce?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=ifup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an auto-negotiation storm can cause infinite packet delay. Set an explicit speed; disable auto-negotiation .

Auto-negotiation storms don't  appear in logs - auto-negotiation is a very low-level hardware "feature".

You can look at the logs. `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: how to disable auto-negotiation in ubuntu?

Comment: add [logging]
level=INFO
to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf so hope to get some details

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.